# Start and Stop two threads at same time

Tags: multithreading, javafx, threadpool

The code below has two threads starting at same time. 
How to start and stop two threads at same time, The first Thread must finish executing and second should stop its process. 
Like I want to process a large file with one thread and show a GIF using another thread in JavaFX

I can use latch to start two threads, but how to stop them at same time

Comment: Threads topics are not specific to javafx. Threads should get a plain java tag.

Comment: *"The code below"** Am I blind or... *"The first Thread must finish executing and second should stop its process"* simply stopping the second thread should acomplish this...